# weighted cumsum rolling with another column

Tags: r

have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
test <- data.frame("name" = c("Scott","Scott","Scott","Scott","Scott","Scott"),
                   "minutes" = c(100, 50, 150, 200, 100, 250),
                   "grade" = c(2, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 2.2, 2.8))
```

I want to make a weighted grade for each row, using cumsum, which shows their average grade weighted with number of minutes -- however I want the sample to only include the most recent rows which account for 400 minutes.

here's an example of the code for `weighted_grade` using cumsum:

```
test <- test %>%
  mutate(weighted_grade = cumsum(grade*minutes)/cumsum(minutes))
```

This does a nice weighted grade for the entire sample, but I'm looking for only the most recent rows which account for 400 minutes.  I looked into rolling sums, but those are based on number of rows rather than amount of hours.

To be clear, I would want the first 3 rows of the new column to return NA (since the first 3 rows add up to 300 minutes and therefore isn't relevant); the 4th row would return the `weighted_grade` of rows 2,3, and 4 (400 minutes total, so 1st row is irrelevant); the 5th row would return `weighted_grade` of rows 3, 4, and 5 (450 minutes); and so on...

Comment: In the example, there is none above 400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) rollapplyr** Group by name and then for each name use `rollapplyr`.  Note that the width can be a vector which we set using `findInterval`.

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))
library(zoo)

test %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(
    minutes0 = ifelse(is.na(minutes), 0, minutes),
    cumsum = cumsum(minutes0),
    mean = rollapplyr(1:n(),
      width = 1:n() - findInterval(cumsum - 400, cumsum),
      FUN = function(ix) if (sum(minutes0[ix]) < 400) NA
        else weighted.mean(grade[ix], minutes0[ix]),
      fill = NA)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(name, minutes, grade, mean)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  name  minutes grade  mean
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Scott     100   2   NA   
2 Scott      50   1.5 NA   
3 Scott     150   2.5 NA   
4 Scott     200   3    2.62
5 Scott     100   2.2  2.66
6 Scott     250   2.8  2.76
```

**2) sqldf** An approach using sql is:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("with t1 as (
    select rowid id, *, sum(minutes) over (partition by name rows unbounded preceding) as cum from test
  )   
  select 
      a.name, 
      a.minutes, 
      a.grade, 
      iif (sum(b.minutes) < 400, Null, sum(b.grade * b.minutes) / sum(b.minutes)) as mean
    from t1 a 
    left join t1 b on b.cum > a.cum  - 400 and b.cum <= a.cum and a.name = b.name
    group by a.id")
```

giving:

```
   name minutes grade     mean
1 Scott     100   2.0       NA
2 Scott      50   1.5       NA
3 Scott     150   2.5       NA
4 Scott     200   3.0 2.625000
5 Scott     100   2.2 2.655556
6 Scott     250   2.8 2.763636
```

### UPDATE

Minor code improvement.

Comment: Actually, it's spitting an error in my big dataset because some rows include NA's. ```Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `proj_blocks`.
x 'vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly and not contain NAs``` I can filter them out before running your code and it works fine, but not sure how to handle this as na.rm = TRUE doesn't exist for cumsum in the width argument?

Comment: Assuming that this refers to NAs in minutes see modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)
#> 
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric
test <- data.frame("name" = c("Scott","Scott","Scott","Scott","Scott","Scott"),
                   "minutes" = c(100, 50, 150, 200, 100, 250),
                   "grade" = c(2, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 2.2, 2.8))
test %>%
  mutate(numerator = grade * minutes,
         cs_numerator = rollapply(numerator,
                                  width = 3,
                                  FUN = sum,
                                  partial = T,
                                  align = "right"),
         cs_denominator = rollapply(minutes,
                                    width = 3,
                                    FUN = sum,
                                    partial = T,
                                    align = "right"),
         res = ifelse(cs_denominator >= 400, cs_numerator / cs_denominator, NA))
#>    name minutes grade numerator cs_numerator cs_denominator      res
#> 1 Scott     100   2.0       200          200            100       NA
#> 2 Scott      50   1.5        75          275            150       NA
#> 3 Scott     150   2.5       375          650            300       NA
#> 4 Scott     200   3.0       600         1050            400 2.625000
#> 5 Scott     100   2.2       220         1195            450 2.655556
#> 6 Scott     250   2.8       700         1520            550 2.763636
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Depending on OP's original data set, I'm not sure if you can always use `width = 3`.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work because it's essentially doing a rolling sum of the last 3 entries.  If the last minutes entry was 400 for example, I would want it to only take the ```weighted_grade``` of the last row.